# how to add horizontal scrollbar in flexislider2

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m using the flexislider2 (http://flex.madebymufffin.com/examples/thumbnail-controlnav.html) with thumbnails and wondering how can we add a horizontal scroll. I m trying to use it on my site (http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/the-work/marlin-lodge-residence-scotland.aspx) and the  thumbnails stack on the top of others.

Comment: You have a lot of javascript errors on the page you have linked. I would correct those and things might start working. [validate your source](http://goo.gl/Ci8bw)

Comment: I have validated the source code as valid html5. Any suggestions now for the slider?

Answer (score 0):

This is too large for a comment so here it goes!

Fix the scripting errors on the page. If you use a tool like firebug on Firefox, Dragonfly on Opera, or Google Chrome, inspect the element and click on the console tab.

Below will solve your issues. Be sure you understand why they will solve most of your issues.

```
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/modernizr.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/froogaloop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/jquery.fitvid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/shBrushCss.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://109.109.245.194/nkarch/js/shBrushJScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As for a horizontal scroll bar you will have to play around with CSS to get it to function as you want. It's not a script issue, it's definitely a style issue. You really might want to consider using [codaslider](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/). It's fully responsive like flexslider but it supports crosslinking which gives you the ability to have two separate sliders linked together. So you can use one as a slider of thumbnails which will, depending on which item the user clicks, will change in a bigger slider elsewhere on the page. I'm sure you can generate those tabs (or do them manually) in ASP. I'm a LAMP developer so I know little about ASP or .NET. Hope this gives you a little bit more information and helps guide you a little bit.